# Plastic SCM community edition for multiple projects

Tags: licensing, plasticscm

I am investigating source control systems and considering migrating from SVN to either GIT or PlasticSCM. However to consider the costs, I'd like to know how much PlasticSCM will cost for us.

On [their website](http://www.plasticscm.com/buy/community-edition-FAQ.aspx) they mention the community edition is free for up to 15 persons per team. However the definition of team is unclear for me: Is it usual in PlasticSCM to create a new repository per project? Or is the 15-person limit valid for all projects that use the same server?

Or in short: Can the community edition be used for two different repositories with 10 people using each?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The license model of PlasticSCM is per-user and per-server.

When a user performs a writable operation in the PlasticSCM server, a license (site) is used. The community edition can be used up to 15 users.

You can have all repositories you want, but you must manage less that 15 users, for each server.

Comment: Yep. 15 people free. Whether you have 1 repo or 100 it doesn't matter.

Comment: Could I have two different repositories with 10 people on each?

Comment: Yes, you can. But your limit with the community edition are 15 people in total working in several repositories (projects).

Comment: So your answer is "no, I can't"? Cause 2 projects with 10 people each sums to 20.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. I understood 10 people working in two projects. If you have 20 people working, the answer is obviouly no.

Comment: @Schiavini: Did I answer your question. In this case, please, close it.

Comment: So the license is per server, and not per repository?

Comment: @Schiavini: That's is. I have edited my answer.